# Drop down: Swap icon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**DROP MENU LINK**
jsfiddle.net/a3MKG/83/

Refer to link above. Does anyone know how to get the navicon image to change upon click? I want it to become a different image (a picture of an X) once I click it.

**Note:** When  you click the navicon, the drop menu comes down, and you can click anywhere OUTSIDE the drop menu to bring the drop menu back up, so you don't have to click the X image to remove the drop down and bring back the initial image. So I need the new navicon image only to be an X when the dropdown menu is **actively** displayed.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you all.

Comment: The code to change the source of an image is document.getElementById("theElement").src = "the path of the image";

Comment: I am very bad with jquery/javascript...can you by any chance implement the code for me in a jsfiddle? I wouldn't know how to use that code

Comment: @miksham the line of code is there. Work it out, it's one line! Learn!!!! This is how we ALL started...

Comment: I honestly tried but I have no idea where to place the code! :(

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work but hasn't been working...

Comment: @miksham i just woke up. Its 4am (in Ireland). I just logged on cos i'm an addict lol. I'm going back to sleep, but will help you in the morning, ie. in about 4 or 5 hours or so... zzzzzzzzzz........ later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I saw your comment re. 'how do I close it just on closing the image' before i made my fiddle.

I changed your div dropTitle to an a and added another class to it menu-open

```
.menu-open{   background:url('http://webservices.lib.harvard.edu/hlportal/images/threeline.png');
     background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

and added a function that toggled it with 'close'

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('close')
});


.close{background:url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/385/010_x-128.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

I tweaked your dropTitle class slightly to

```
.dropTitle{
  display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

but the functionality remains the same

Comment: Hi Rachel! Thanks so much for your help. It works great but you missed part of my comment...there is a mistake here. When you click the icon, it turns to an X (great)...bad part is you don't necessarily have to click the X to close the menu. You can click the menu itself or anywhere around the page...so the X still appears when it shouldn't. How do you make so that the menu ONLY opens and closes when you click the icon, not anywhere else around the page? Thank you again!

Comment: @miksham the menu only opens and closes if you click the icon- did you not try the fiddle? By the way an upvote never goes astray!

Comment: @miksham OK I tried the fiddle again and realised that it does close if you click anywhere. That's because you have that HTML.click function in the code. I'll update the fiddle later, I'm on the bus home from a party at the moment. I don't see an upvote???

Comment: Checked your answer and upvoted you :) awaiting your response. Thanks so much again!

Comment: 2:55 am and tipsy - see i'm dedicated! http://jsfiddle.net/9ow48u5d/ btw, thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use javascript where you can use css!

```css
input, input:before, input:after {
  display: block;
  content:'';
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  width:20px;
  background:black;
  height:4px;
  border-radius:2px;
  transition: all linear 0.1s;
}
input:after{
  top:3px;
}
input:before{
  top:-7px;
}
input:focus:after{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top:-4px;
}
input:focus{
  background:transparent;
}
input:focus:before{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top:0px;
}
input:not(:focus) + div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<div>
  <img class="dropPillow" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/square-outlined-shape_318-75498.png">
</div>
```

Comment: thats a big square! try adding size Peter!

Comment: @RachelGallen The square is not important to the question and not important to the answer. The problem is solved, no need for aesthetic operations.

Comment: its important to how the dropdown appears! i replaced it in the css originally and it came up weird (without adding a size). And aesthetics are rather important in website DESIGN!

Comment: @RachelGallen You made something wrong, maybe you forgot to remove the javascript or you wrote the css wrong, or broke the html. I realy dont know what you made wrong, and it is a different question i think.*See:* if i add all the css/html stuff from the question we loose the *point* and the very bad design fault to use javascript instead of css will survive.